# when can a surface conformally equivalent to the sphere be isometrically immersed?

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

Given a scalar function $s:S^2\to \mathbb{R}$, and the induced Euclidean metric $g$ on $S^2$, when can the sphere, equipped with metric $e^sg$, be isometrically immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Is there a characterization in terms of $s$?

I believe that for the analogous problem in 2D, the disk can be isometrically immersed in the plane if the conformal factor is harmonic.

Comment: [Related](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/218766/isometric-imbedding-of-a-sphere-with-positively-curved-metric): Seems that having positive curvature on $e^s g$ is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMa, yes it seems the difficult/"interesting" case is when the resulting metric has regions of negative curvature